# How to Loop and merge queries in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to generate a output that looksup a distinct group of candidate ID's in (8) specific tests. Since the issue is candidates can take multiple tests and due to data errors I need to find unique values per test.

The basic SQL to lookup this would be the following:

```
 SELECT 
 DISTINCT ON (candidate_Id) candidate_Id,
 Test_id
 FROM [database] 
 WHERE candidate_Id in ('[long list of ids]') 
      AND Test_id in ('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008')
```

^ But because of the "Distinct" on ids, it will filter them out of the other tests they may have taken.

The ideal outcome: Where I return the unqiue value candidate ID on a per test basis and have it all generated in one single output.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `Test_id` to the `DISTINCT ON` clause like this to achieve what you want:

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT ON (candidate_Id, Test_id) candidate_Id, Test_id
FROM [database] 
WHERE candidate_Id in ('[long list of ids]')
   AND Test_id in ('001','002','003','004','005','006','007','008')
```